# Intuition behind the alternative property of Determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, determinant

I am trying to prove the alternating property of the determinant. From what I have seen as far as now everything resolves around the idea that if I have a matrix and begin to switch columns/rows then the amount of switches required to return to the original matrix will determine my sign.

Example: Let this matrix be A and be the original matrix

\begin{pmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}

Now switch the colums. 
\begin{pmatrix} 
b & a \\
d & c 
\end{pmatrix}

The derminant of this new matrix will be (-1)(D|A|) because it takes one column switch to go to original. This expression is generalized by $(-1)^{n};$ n = the amount of switches.

My question is where does this $(-1)^{n}$ come from. What is its logic/intuition behind it. I'm not looking for an answer that says if its odd its negative even positive. I'd like to genuinely understand. Please give me a basic answer that I can eventually expand on.

Thank you for your time

Comment: How do you define the determinant? Using the Leibniz formula it is immediate why switching columns gives you the change in sign.

Comment: @Riquelme that doesn't really answer the question because it doesn't explain the logic or intuition behind why that should be so. A better question than "how do you define the determinant?" is "what is the determinant supposed to represent?"

Comment: sorry I am not familiar with Leibniz. Would you mind expanding on that. A determinant I try to view it as a way of telling whether columns/rows are linearly dependent/ independent but I know I can also represent area and things as such

Comment: @79037662 You think answering with a single example in $R^2$ gives a deeper understanding? There is no' logic ' involved, when you compute the determinant you use some definition as well, along with its properties like multilinearity and so on.

Comment: @Riquelme was referring to this: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants Or, if you prefer: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Levi-Civita_symbol

Comment: @Riquelme In my opinion it is a pedagogical mistake to teach the determinant as just some calculations you perform on an array of numbers, without explaining why those calculations are meaningful or what they represent (which seems to be more or less what OP is asking). Of course there is logic involved, the definition wasn't pulled out of thin air.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix represents a linear transformation of your space (in this case $\mathbb{R}^2$), and a linear transformation can distort space. The determinant tells you how much the area of some given shape in the space will change after the transformation.

For example, the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$ represents a scaling in both directions by 2. The determinant of this matrix is 4 because any given shape, when scaled in both directions by 2, will have an area 4 times as large.

The determinant being negative means the transformation also "flips" shapes around. Switching the columns of a matrix will have the effect of switching the final positions of the corresponding basis vectors; this will create the effect of "flipping" the space.

Comment: YouTuber 3blue1brown has a video series on linear algebra which gives good geometric intuition behind things like these.

Comment: Thank you that is actually very interesting. I did know that a determinant can help you find your change/ volume in r^2 and r^3 but didn't imagine that a negative determinant would flip the area. I'll look into the video thanks